# Why does my image leave the screen if the X/Y is set to anything but 0?

Tags: javafx

I am trying to make the bouncing DVD logo as a means of learning to use timeline and keyframe in javaFX. The problem I am running in to is if I set the X/Y of the image to anything other than 0,0 the image will go further than the bounds of the screen. I am just confused on why this is happening and what I need to do to fix it. Thank you!

I have tried setting the image to different areas on the pane. I have tried subtracting more than just the dvd width and height to compensate. I have tried many things.

```
public class Main extends Application {
    Stage window;

    private final int WIDTH = 700;
    private final int HEIGHT = 700;

    private Timeline timeline;

    private double xSpeed = 3;
    private double ySpeed = 3;

    private Parent createContent() {
        Pane root = new Pane();
        root.setPrefSize(WIDTH,HEIGHT);

        ImageView dvd = new ImageView(new Image("/dvd.png"));
        dvd.setFitHeight(100);
        dvd.setFitWidth(100);
        dvd.setPreserveRatio(true);
        dvd.setX(100);
        dvd.setY(100);

        dvd.setPreserveRatio(true);

        timeline = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(16), e-> {
            dvd.setTranslateX(dvd.getTranslateX() + xSpeed);
            dvd.setTranslateY(dvd.getTranslateY() + ySpeed);

            if (xSpeed + dvd.getTranslateX() >= WIDTH - dvd.getFitWidth()){
                xSpeed = -xSpeed;
            } else if(xSpeed + dvd.getTranslateX() <= 0)
                xSpeed = -xSpeed;

            if (ySpeed + dvd.getTranslateY() >= HEIGHT - dvd.getFitHeight()){
                ySpeed = -ySpeed;
            } else if(ySpeed + dvd.getTranslateY() <= 0)
                ySpeed = -ySpeed;

        }));

        timeline.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
        timeline.play();

        root.getChildren().add(dvd);

        return root;
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        window = primaryStage;
        Scene mainScene = new Scene(createContent(),WIDTH,HEIGHT);

        window.setResizable(false);
        window.setTitle("Bouncing DVD");
        window.setScene(mainScene);
        window.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

I expect to be able to place the DVD image anywhere on the screen and for it to bounce off of the walls of the scene.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `x` and `y` properties of `ImageView` are ways of moving the `ImageView` from it's usual position without affecting the translate properties. Any changes of the rendering position by transforms such as the translate properties happen in addition to this change.

The x and y ranges where the image is rendered are `[x+translateX, x+translateX+fitWidth)` and`[y+translateY, y+translateY+fitHeight)` respectively.

The simplest way of fixing this issue is using only a single property per dimension, e.g. `translateX` and `translateY`:

```
dvd.setFitHeight(100);
dvd.setFitWidth(100);
dvd.setPreserveRatio(true);
dvd.setTranslateX(100);
dvd.setTranslateY(100);
```